# Footer does not show up at the end of the page

Tags: php, html, css

I'm creating a webpage that contains tables that pull data from mysql database. When I want to add a footer, footer does not show up at the bottom of the page. I've tried html's regular footer class, bootstrap footer, sticky footer but none of them worked. I've also tried all `position` values. Even though I write random stuff at the bottom of the code, before the body closing tag, it still shows it at the beginning.

You can see the page from: http://sagtekin.com/letseat/donat.php

Thank you very much for your help.

Edit: Code is below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
<meta content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-9" http-equiv="content-type">
<meta content="text/html;charset=windows-1254" http-equiv="content-type">
<meta content="text/html;charset=x-mac-turkish" http-equiv="content-type">
<script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.2/material.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.2/material.indigo-pink.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/w3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<title>Let's Eat - Donatello Pizza</title>
<style>
body {
    background: url(background/bg-03.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
#infoCard {
    background: #FAFAFA;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
#header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 6px rgba(101, 94, 94, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 6px rgba(101, 94, 94, 0.75);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 6px rgba(101, 94, 94, 0.75);
}
div {
    border-radius: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<header id="header" class="w3-container w3-teal">
    <h1><b>LET'S EAT</b></h1>
</header>
<div class="w3-responsive">
    <div class="w3-third  w3-container">
    </div>
    <div class="w3-third w3-container">
        <div id="infoCard" class="w3-card-16">
            <header class="w3-container w3-teal">
                <h1>Donatello Pizza</h1>
            </header>
            <p style="color: #4CAF50; text-align: center; margin-top: 10px; font-size: large; vertical-align: middle;">
            <b>OPEN</b></p>
            <hr />
            <div>
                <p id="textDisplay" style="text-align: center">Hover your mouse 
                over the buttons.</p>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="tel:05338643695" onmouseout="resetText()" onmouseover="changeTextTurkcell()">
                Turkcell</a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="tel:05488643695" onmouseout="resetText()" onmouseover="changeTextTelsim()">
                Telsim</a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="tel:03927147083" onmouseout="resetText()" onmouseover="changeTextLandLine()">
                Landline</a>
                <script>

                        function changeTextTurkcell()
                        {
                            document.getElementById("textDisplay").innerHTML="<b>0533 864 3695</b>";
                        }

                        function changeTextTelsim()
                        {
                            document.getElementById("textDisplay").innerHTML="<b>0548 864 3695</b>";
                        }

                        function changeTextLandLine()
                        {
                            document.getElementById("textDisplay").innerHTML="<b>0392 714 7083</b>";
                        }

                        function resetText()
                        {
                            document.getElementById("textDisplay").innerHTML="Hover your mouse over the buttons.";
                        }

                      </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-third w3-container">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="w3-quarter w3-container">
</div>
<div class="w3-half w3-container">
    <div class="w3-responsive w3-card-16" style="margin-top: 50px; background-color: #FAFAFA">
        <header class="w3-container w3-pink">
            <h3>Breakfast</h3>
        </header>
        <table class="table">
        <!--Table contents-->   
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-responsive w3-card-16" style="margin-top: 30px; background-color: #FAFAFA">
        <header class="w3-container w3-pink">
            <h3>Pizzas</h3>
        </header>
        <table class="table">
        <!--Table contents-->   
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-responsive w3-card-16" style="margin-top: 30px; background-color: #FAFAFA">
        <header class="w3-container w3-pink">
            <h3>Chicken</h3>
        </header>
        <table class="table">
        <!--Table contents-->   
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-responsive w3-card-16" style="margin-top: 30px; background-color: #FAFAFA">
        <header class="w3-container w3-pink">
            <h3>Pasta</h3>
        </header>
        <table class="table">
        <!--Table contents-->   
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-responsive w3-card-16" style="margin-top: 30px; background-color: #FAFAFA">
        <header class="w3-container w3-pink">
            <h3>Other</h3>
        </header>
        <table class="table">
        <!--Table contents-->   
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-quarter w3-container">
    </div>
</div>
<!--<div class="w3-container w3-teal" style="position:absolute;  bottom:0px;">
    <h5>LET'S EAT</h5>
    <p>&copy; 2015 Poyraz Sagtekin.</p>
    </div>-->ergkjlhkjgekjhjkhjwhwjhgwhgwhgwkhgrlgrwhjlhkjgwhr

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Show us the code of your page, please.

Comment: It's a long code, you can open the page on chrome and click on view page's source thing.

Comment: Please add the code. Not everyone is on  their laptops to do it that way, there are geeks (like me) on phone too!

Comment: I don't see any footer in the HTML.

Comment: I also peeked at your sources and it appears that you've written 'random stuff' outside any `<div>` bootstrap container.

Comment: ok I'm putting the source code :)

Comment: Your problem could also be caused by PHP, which does *not* show up in the page source.

Comment: I inspected it, and I can't see any code for the footer at all. Seems it simply isn't being written.

Comment: Just post relevant parts of the code, like the part that should be rendering your so-expected footer

Comment: I guess his footer is `ergkjlhkjgekjhjkhjwhwjhgwhgwhgwkhgrlgrwhjlhkjgwh` Clearly not working from PHP side.

Comment: @ManojKumar it's **not** a footer at all. It's not wrapped inside any tag with such function nor property. That why it's screwed, but without the source it's vague to say.

Comment: Yes, I guessed the PHP error/bug/mistake was not wrapping the `<div>` inside `<?php ?>` or something. Unable to see until PHP code is posted.

Comment: No, the thing is everything i put there as a footer shows up at the top parts of the page. That is the problem :)) I put that random stuff to show it to you  :) But I think that was a wrong move :)

Comment: @rj want a cookie? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I isolated what I presumed to be your footer code which was a string of letters like:

`ergkjlhkjgekjhjkhjwhwjhgwhgwhgwkhgrlgrwhjlhkjgwhr`

I wrapped that in a div with the following styles and it appeared at the bottom of the page:

```
<div style="clear:both;">
    ergkjlhkjgekjhjkhjwhwjhgwhgwhgwkhgrlgrwhjlhkjgwhr
</div>
```

It appears you just need to `clear` your previous element to "force" your footer to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Extension to @Samuels answer, you must put that in a `<div>` or a `<footer>` tag and then style it by simply using `clear: both;` or you could add more to it like `position: fixed;` `bottom: 0;` `line-height: 15px;` the list could go on and on.